# Blazor EDGE link.Click()

Tags: file, download, blazor

This example https://blazorfiddle.com/s/o8g3elz1 does not work in Edge:

```js
function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    //link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
    link.href = "data:," + bytesBase64;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public async static Task LinkToFile(IJSRuntime js, string filename, byte[] data) {
    var tempFileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("."));
    var path = ".\\wwwroot\\downloads\\" + tempFileName;
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, data).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await js.InvokeAsync < object > ("linkToFile", filename, "/downloads/" + tempFileName);
    //File.Delete(path);
}
```

```js
function linkToFile(filename, url) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = url;
    link.target = "_blank";
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using

```
lnk.href = objectURL = url.createObjectURL(blob);
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

You should read the following articles, it helps to implement the download functionality:

- [Create and download a file in JS](https://chuvash.eu/2016/05/15/create-and-download-a-file-in-javascript/)
- [Create and download a file in javascript](http://tech.bool.se/create-download-file-javascript/)

Hoewever, my solution is a bit different as I didn't want sending base64 data from Blazor server-side to the client and I could avoid js at all. I've create Web API controllers that delivers files and just use a simple a href. Example:

```
<a href="/api/GetPdf/1234" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

The key is to use **target="_blank"** so that the file can be saved and doesn't open in-place of the current site.